# cooling system vw

Tags: vw, coolant, cooling-system, water-leak, coolant-leak

i have a golf 4 gti engine 2.0 for the year 2002,the problem is when i pour water in the container it does not hold water,instead it leaks i can't see where the water is leaking,all the pipes connected to the container do not show where exactly water comes from,i only find the water coming out at the bottom near the the belts,im very sory i dont know what these parts are called,please help me.

Comment: Are you talking about the windshield washer bottle, or something else? What are you putting water into? Does the weather ever get below 0 deg C (32 def F) where you are? If so I wouldn't put water into anything...

Comment: Even if you _do_ put water in it, it really needs to be distilled water.

Answer (score 2):

As a first step to helping you answer your question it will be helpful to familiarize yourself with the cooling system. I would recommend this video as a short introduction.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J48JLu_L5cY

There are several components that may fail in the cooling system. Here is a list of places where leaks can typically occur.

1. A cracked radiator or reservoir
2. A bad hose, or a loose connection between a hose and another component
3. The radiator cap
4. The thermostat housing (if the gasket goes bad)
5. The water pump (again if the gasket goes bad)

Inspect each part thoroughly. Look for buildup of coolant as an indicator. Leaks will be worse when the engine gets warm because this causes the coolant to expand.  If you are having trouble finding the leak, I would recommend filling up the system, then warming the engine to make it easier to spot. You can also purchase fluorescent coolant dye to help you spot the leak easier.

Finally, since you mention that you poured in water, I should mention that it is not good to run straight water in your cooling system.  It should be a 50/50 mix of water and coolant.

Comment: The VW coolant system has several plastic housings and connectors that are prone to cracking over time.  I'm more familiar with the VR6, but the 2.0 probably has at least a temperature sensor housing and thermostat housing that are made from plastic that becomes brittle after 10 years or so.